# Relating Members to each other

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, member-management

I'm trying to figure out how (if possible) to relate members to each other. I have teachers registering with Zoo Visitor and are added as Teacher Member Group. They need to be able to then assign Assistants to their account so that they are tied into each other.

So Teacher John would have Assistant Bob and Assistant Jane.
Teacher Elvis would have Assistant Bob and Assistant Mary and Assistant Trevor.

Any thoughts on how this would be possible, if at all in EE?

Answer (score 0):

Are the assistants members too? If not, Install PT Field Pack. You can use PT checkboxes as a field in your Zoo Member Profile. Then populate it with assistants. Then when teachers register, they can check off their assistants and you can display them through a members details page.

If they are members, you could do the same thing, but just write an import script that grabs assistants from the members database and populates new ones in that field type.

Blatant and I worked out a solution to a somewhat similar problem here:

[Complex Member permissions](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/31353/complex-member-permissions)

Not sure if it fits your needs, but it worked for me!

Comment: Or if teachers and assistants are both EE Zoo Members, you could install Matrix, and populate it with relationship or Playa fields! Zoo Members are channel entries!